# Can we send mail(abc@reddifmail.com to another mail Address) through JavaMail API?

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I am using `JavaMail API` and I'm able to send mail  **from** `abc@gmail.com` **to** `xyz@gmail.com`.

Now, what I want:

**I want to send email from abc@rediffmail.com to xyz@mail.com  etc / etc.**

outgoing mail server : smtp.rediffmail.com

port no : 25

o/p :javax.mail.AuthenticationExcepetion ,

what  change is necessary foe it or IS this possible or not .

Comment: Hope this you get your answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a

Comment: I did this but I want to send mail to the other domain as I mention in my above query @shree202

Comment: I don't understand.  You just change the "to" email address.  What's the real question?

Comment: @Simon  If I'll change the email address(yahoo.com) .... on that mail I'm not getting the mail but In gmail.com .... case .... I m getting the mail

Comment: Check your junk mail folder

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet changing your SMTP server.
Yahoo: 
Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP): plus.smtp.mail.yahoo.com 
Use SSL, port: 465, use authentication.

Snippet:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", myEmail);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", smptServer);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();

    try {
        Authenticator auth = new autentificadorSMTP();
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
        // session.setDebug(true);

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setText(body);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(myEmail));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(
                toEmail));
        Transport.send(msg);
    } catch (Exception mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Util:

```
    private class authSMTP extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(myEmail, myPass);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: 10-14 17:43:36.482: W/System.err(32726): javax.mail.MessagingException: [EOF]

Comment: Give us more info about smtp server doing session.setDebug(true) please :)

Comment: what is value should I use for SMTP Server

Comment: Look at this link: http://email.about.com/od/accessingyahoomail/f/Yahoo_Mail_SMTP_Settings.htm

Comment: post the whole trace please